# kubernetes "unauthorized: authentication required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have one GKE Cluster which uses the AWS ECR repo to pull the docker images. These are the steps that I followed.

Created a secret using this command

```
# cat > /tmp/image-pull-secret.yaml << EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: $(aws ecr get-authorization-token --output json | jq -n 'input.authorizationData | {auths: (reduce .[]  as $d ({}; . + {($d.proxyEndpoint|sub("https?://";"")): {auth:$d.authorizationToken}}))}' | (base64 -w0 2>/dev/null || base64) )
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
EOF

# kubectl apply -f /tmp/image-pull-secret.yaml
```

Created a deployment but getting error

```
# cat abc_deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc-deployment
  labels:
    app: abc
    env: development
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: abc
      env: development
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc
        env: development
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: abc
        image: 34235354354.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-abc:1.1.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
```

Error I am getting
++++++++++++++++++

```
  Normal   Pulling                1m (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-puppy-default-pool-e701eb52-6gdp  pulling image "34235354354.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-abc:1.1.1"
  Warning  Failed                 1m (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-puppy-default-pool-e701eb52-6gdp  Failed to pull image "34235354354.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-abc:1.1.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unauthorized: authentication required
  Warning  Failed                 1m (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-puppy-default-pool-e701eb52-6gdp  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                1m (x6 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-puppy-default-pool-e701eb52-6gdp  Back-off pulling image "34235354354.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-abc:1.1.1"
  Warning  Failed                 1m (x6 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-puppy-default-pool-e701eb52-6gdp  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

How can we fix this error?

Comment: Please post it on serverFault https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

*Technically* your approach of putting the docker auth token into the `imagePullSecret` should work - it is what the [Kubernetes documentation on integrating a private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) recommends as well.

The *problem* however is that the docker auth token for ECR [is only valid for 12 hours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html). Maybe the authentication error only occurred after that period of time?

Instead what you could do, is to create a CronJob that refreshes the docker auth token and recreates the `imagePullSecret` (you can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190763/8301780), [here](https://medium.com/@xynova/keeping-aws-registry-pull-credentials-fresh-in-kubernetes-2d123f581ca6), or [here](https://dev.to/anaganisk/integrating-aws-ecr-elastic-container-registry-with-kubernetes-1c1i)).

There are also pre-built docker images for that purpose, e.g. [ecr-kube-helper](https://github.com/anaganisk/ecr-kube-helper) or [k8s-ecr-login-renew](https://github.com/nabsul/k8s-ecr-login-renew).